# OpenCV Android - convert MatOfPoint to Mat

Tags: android, opencv

I'd like to convert a MatOfPoint found with Imgproc.findContours into a (binary) Mat.  I know there's a way to do the reverse conversion (just use the constructor MatOfPoint(Mat m)) but is there a built-in way to do this conversion?  If not, what is the correct way to convert element-by-element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need any converters. MatOfPoint is a subclass of Mat:

From OpenCV source:

```
public class MatOfPoint extends Mat
```

Comment: It should, but I get this error when using matToBitmap: `Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: ..\..\modules\java\generator\src\cpp\utils.cpp:106: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4 in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, _jclass*, jlong, _jobject*, jboolean)`

Comment: I think you need a `Imgproc.drawContours()` method to visualize your contours. The underlying structure of `MatOfPoint` is 2-channel vector of integers (you can think is as a list of 2D Points with integer coordinates). As result `Utils.matToBitmap()` rejects `MatOfPoint` because it expects 8-bit per channel image.