# how to convert List<MatofPoint> to Mat in opencv?

Tags: opencv, mat

Recently I'm developing android app using `OpenCV`. Now I encounter a problem:

```
Imgproc.findContours(grayMat, contours1, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

After this function, I want to call `Imgproc.MatchShapes` to detect whether 2 images are matched. but under Java edition MatchShapes requires parameters of  type Mat.
How can I convert `List<MatOfPoint>` to Mat?

Comment: not sure about java but contours1 should be sth like ListOfListOfPoints (because each contour should be a list of points)

Comment: You don't need to, as seen from [MatOfPoint class extends Mat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380594/opencv-android-convert-matofpoint-to-mat

Answer (score 0):

The function you use to detect contours returns a list of `MatOfPoints`. Each contour - because there can be many - has its own `MatOfPoints`.

You have to find a way to choose which contour you want to use with `Imgproc.MatchShapes`. If you know there's only one, then just use the first entry in the `List<MatOfPoints>`. If you want the biggest one, use some contour properties to find the biggest contour. If you have time, you can check every single contour.

Then, once you've found the single contour you want to compare, you can use that `MatOfPoints`. According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380594/opencv-android-convert-matofpoint-to-mat), they are perfectly compatible.